# Run all tests in PHPunit at once but isolated from each other

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Some of my tests contains `ob_start();` which causes an issue if the I simply run `vendor/bin/phpunit` (run all tests at once) however if I isolate the tests one by one via `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter mytest`, they work fine.

Is there a way to run the tests "all at once" but internally "isolated"?

Comment: did you try     $actualOutput = ob_get_clean();         $this->assertSame($actualOutput,$expectedOutput);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [runInSeparateProcess option](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess)